# My iOS7 app crashes when I add an extra row to my UITableViewController dedicated to my load more results feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, parse-platform

Using parse.com's PFQueryTableViewController. All is working fine with a search bar also. The problem I have now is my "load more" which is a feature included with this new tableViewController isn't showing anymore.

I guess it's something to do with me overriding the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Everything else seems to be working as normal. Correct number of results are returned, pull to refresh works fine. I have a feeling the functionality for "load more" is still there but because I added that number of rows method I've overridden it's default behavior and now the load more row isn't visible.

**My initializer:**

```
@interface MPPeopleTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *people;
    NSArray *searchResults;

}

@end

@implementation MPPeopleTableViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // This table displays items in my People class on parse.com
        [self setParseClassName: @"People"];
        [self setPullToRefreshEnabled: YES];
        [self setPaginationEnabled: YES];
        [self setObjectsPerPage: 5];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Query for table:**

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache
    // first to fill the table and then subsequently do a query
    // against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query whereKey:@"active" equalTo:@1];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}
```

**Methods for search bar:**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [[self objects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

**Datasource methods:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.


    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {


        return [[self objects] count];
    }

}
```

**Final datasource method:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *current;


    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
        current = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        current = [[self objects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

        // Maybe need to grab image synchro instead
        PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];
        [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.textLabel.text = [current objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [current objectForKey:@"notes"];
    }];



    return cell;
}
```

I have a strong feeling the issue is coming from the number of rows method. Everytime I try to add an extra row my app crashes. I think I'm missing something. All I do is add +1 after the line that returns my number of rows e.g. `return [[self objects] count] + 1;` and this causes the app to crash.

**Can you show and explain the steps I need to take to add that extra row that is needed for the "Load More" row. When I remove the number of rows method is comes back and all is fine but then my search feature doesn't work.**

Would appreciate some help thanks.

Kind regards

**Update**

**Updated number of rows in section method:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
        return [searchResults count];   
    } else {    
        return [[self objects] count] + 1;
    }
}
```

**Updated cell for row and index path method:**

```
if (indexPath.row == self.objects.count) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Load More";
} else {
   PFObject *current;
    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
        current = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        current = [[self objects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Maybe need to grab image synchro instead
    PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.textLabel.text = [current objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [current objectForKey:@"notes"];
    }];

}
```

Comment: Once I've got that extra row working all I can simple detect it's selection and call [self loadNextPage] and i'll be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was to do this an entirely different way. I've pasted code and comments below to show others exactly how. Hope this helps.

**Inside my viewWillAppear:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Create a new view to a specific size
    UIView *loadMoreView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 718, 239, 50)];
    [loadMoreView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Make this view the footer of my tableview
    [[self tableView] setTableFooterView: loadMoreView];


    // Create the button
    UIButton *loadMoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    // Set the size of the button to fill up the view it's within
    [loadMoreButton setFrame: loadMoreView.bounds];

    // Set the title and colour
    [loadMoreButton setTitle:@"Load More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Connect up an action to trigger loadNextPage method when button is tapped
    [loadMoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMoreButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Add this new button to the loadMoreView
    [loadMoreView addSubview:loadMoreButton]; // add the button to bottom view

}
```

**IBAction for loading more results:**

```
- (IBAction)loadMoreButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self loadNextPage];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you return in numberOfRowsInSection: is taken as gospel for how many rows you have.  In addition, you MUST in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: be able to handle providing a cell for any of those rows, which means if the additional row presents an index that is higher than the count of either searchResults or [self objects], then you overstepped a bound.  I'd put a breakpoint in

```
    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
```

when you add the row and see how many are in the array, and what the value of indexPath.row is.

Comment: This didn't show anything but I added some logs and at viewDidLoad my objects NSArray is empty and at viewDidAppear it's 5 which is what I've set my limit to. If you check my comment below it's telling me my array is empty.

Comment: Yes, but by adding +1, you're telling the system there are 6 rows, but when it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath, when it tries to get the data for row 6, it exceeds how many things are in the array.

Comment: I tried again and step over again and again and it showed there are 5 objects in the objects array and the searchResults instance method is always nil and will always be nil until the search bar is actually used.

Comment: There are only 5 things in the array, but when you tell numberOfRowsInSection: there are 6, it will call your cellForRowAtIndexPath and then it calls objectAtIndex: on your array for the 6th item, but there are only five, thus you crash.  Your bug is in asking the array for an item outside its bounds.

Comment: It's starting to make sense to me now. So I need to some how stop that from ever happening. How would you suggest I do that? I added an if statement to only allow that objectAtIndex line to run if indexPath.row's number is <= to the amount of objects. Same issue.

Comment: If you breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which is probably where you're failing, you can look at what the index numbers are in the debugger.  You can also type 'po searchResults' or 'po [self objects]' and actually see what's there. You need to have data available for every cell you say you have in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: I put a breakpoint where you suggested and logged the indexPath and I'm getting 0 to 4 then when I add +1 on numberOfRowsInSection and run the app again as soon as the app is started it crashes and I get the error in the comment in Marius's answer. It crashes before it can step in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: +1 doesn't add a row to your list.  It's only telling the system that you have one more item then is really there in your array.  You should not increase the row count, instead increase the array and have the row count report the real size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the app will crash if you tell it that there is an extra row, because it will then call cellForRowAtIndexPath one extra time, and exceed the bounds of the array of objects.

If you want to force an extra row like that, you would also need to handle the extra row specifically in cellForRow...

I am not sure how the "Load more" function works. I had pagination set to YES once, but didn't get a Load more-row. I didn't need it, so I just set it to NO.

If you remove the +1, the app doesn't crash, right?

In cellForRow, check if the indexPath.row == self.objects.count. If it is, then you have the "Load more" row, and need to handle that specifically. Then, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can load more results.

**UPDATE**

This is a slightly edited example code from the Anypic tutorial app (because that uses 1 section for each object). As NSIndexPath starts on index 0, the test against self.objects.count should then point to the row AFTER the last (meaning the extra pagination cell). I believe this should work for you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.row == self.objects.count && self.paginationEnabled) {
        // Load More Cell
        [self loadNextPage];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you scroll up and check my updates I've made the changes and get this error: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'. However when the "+1" is removed the error is gone.

Comment: Hmm, you have to check for self.objects.count + 1 there as well... But did you ever check the PFQueryTableViewController.h ? There is a cellForNextPageAtIndexPath method there. Did you try using it?

Comment: Still crashes and gives same error. That method you suggested only matters when the actual load more cell is showing doesn't it? As soon as numberOfRowsInSection is overridden the load more cell disappears. This is proving to be very difficult.

Comment: Ok, let me get this straight. If you do not override numberOfRowsInSection, you get the load more cell automatically? So what is wrong when it DOES show? Can you tap it?

Comment: If I don't override I get the load more cell and it works correctly but I need to override in order to have my searchbar work correctly. I implemented a button just to check the [self loadNextPage] works and it does. So all I need to do is add another row, give it a title load more then add that [self loadNextPage].

Comment: Is it always crashing, or only when searching? If you need pagination when searching, you would need to add a +1 to the search results count as well ( return [searchResults count] + 1; )

Comment: Nope crashes straight away. It doesn't ever know about the searchBar yet. Detects when it's clicked. I actually tried to comment out all the search bar code in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath too but get the same issue. Crashes straight away with the error above. As soon as I remove the +1 from numberOfRowsInSection method the crash is gone.

Comment: What is "right away"? Did you try adding a breakpoint in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to see which row it crashes on?